# AndEngine and smooth rotate sprite

Tags: android, andengine

I want to smooth rotate my spirtes. I have 6 sprites and I want to rotate them on 360. 
This is my code:

```
unactiveTimerWaitingForPlayersTxtSprite
                .registerUpdateHandler(timerToUnactiveTimerWaitingTxt);
TimerHandler timerToUnactiveTimerWaitingTxt = new TimerHandler(0.1f, true,
        new ITimerCallback() {
            public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                unactiveTimerWaitingForPlayersTxtSprite
                        .setRotation(unactiveTimerWaitingForPlayersTxtSprite
                                .getRotation() - ANGLE_WAITING_TXT);
            }
        });
```

This is code for one sprite. For all my sprites I do that in the same way. When I run application on Asus transformer 700 rotate of objects is not smooth. I add this code to engine:

```
 engineOptions.getRenderOptions().setDithering(true);
        engineOptions.getRenderOptions().setMultiSampling(true);
```

but still the same effect. There is any way to smooth rotate objects?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Modifiers`: In this case you are looking for the `RotationModifier`.

If you want to rotate the sprites using custom TimerHandlers then you have to multiply the angle change (ANGLE_WAITING_TXT) with the elapsed time in order to have a smooth animation.